# When Hash's default value is set as Hash, it is giving unexpected output

Tags: ruby

I was experimenting with Ruby's default Hash values in v2.3.7. I was surprised by some output I got in a simple test case, and I was wondering what was going on behind the scenes that would explain it.

```
foo = Hash.new({x: 0, y: 0}) # provide a default value 
foo['bar'][:x] += 1          # expect to add to the default value
foo                          # outputs `{}` ?! expected {'bar'=>{:x=>1,:y=>0}}
foo['bar']                   # outputs `{:x=>1, :y=>0}` as expected
```

Why is it that `foo` appears to be empty on line 3? I expected output like `{'bar'=>{:x=>1,:y=>0}}`. Am I missing something super basic about why this is happening? `foo.empty?` returns `true`, but `foo['bar']` produces output.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I think this may be related to the idea that providing a default value that is itself an object means that every entry in `foo` actually points to *the same object*. Changing one of them changes all entries, since the default object isn't copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the default value, no key/value is set. The default is simply returned instead of `nil`.

I think you're imagining it works like this where the default is set on the key being accessed like `||=`.

```
default = {x: 0, y: 0}
foo = Hash.new
foo['bar'] ||= default 
foo['bar'][:x] += 1
```

Instead, it works like this where the default is returned when there is no key.

```
default = {x: 0, y: 0}
foo = Hash.new
val = foo['bar'] || default
val[:x] += 1
```

Put another way, you're expecting this.

```
def [](key)
  @data[key] ||= default
end
```

But it works like this.

```
def [](key)
  @data[key] || default
end
```

---

> *But this behaviour appears to change if I provide, say, an integer instead of a Hash as the default value. For instance, if I do foo = Hash.new(1), then foo['bar'] += 1 the behaviour is what I would expect. foo is not empty, and the default value has not changed. – aardvarkk 4 mins ago*

`foo['bar'] += 1` is really shorthand for

```
default = foo['bar']        # fetch the default
foo['bar'] = default + 1    # sets 'bar' on foo
```

Note that it calls `[]=` on `foo`.

`foo['bar'][:x] += 1` is shorthand for...

```
default = foo['bar']   # fetch the default value
val = default[:x]      # fetch :x from the default
default[:x] = val + 1  # set :x on the default value
```

Note that it calls `[]=` on the default value, not `foo`.

Comment: But this behaviour appears to change if I provide, say, an integer instead of a Hash as the default value. For instance, if I do `foo = Hash.new(1)`, then `foo['bar'] += 1` the behaviour is what I would expect. `foo` is not empty, and the default value has not changed.

Comment: That's what I explained, in case where default is an integer, and your recieving key is `bar`, `bar` is created and added to hash `foo`, in case of your question, when default is hash, your recieving key is `x` and not `bar` so `x` is changed as expected and no change is done to `bar` / `foo`.@aardvarkk

Comment: @aardvarkk I've added a further explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are changing the default value and not assigning new key to the hash.
Can be understood by calling any key to the hash e.g.

```
foo['bar']
=> {:x=>1, :y=>0}
foo['foobar']
=> {:x=>1, :y=>0}
```

Another way of looking at it,

```
foo['bar'][:x] += 1
=> 2

foo['bar']
=> {:x=>2, :y=>0}

foo['bar'][:x] += 1
=> 3

foo['bar']
=> {:x=>3, :y=>0}

foo['bar'][:x] + 1
=> 4

foo['bar']
=> {:x=>3, :y=>0} # here the value is not assigned so not changed - as expected
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this that behaves the way I was expecting? I would assume when accessing a key value that didn't exist, it would be created. Isn't that the way hashes normally work in Ruby?

Comment: No, because, you assigned / manipulated the key `x` which is changed as expected but since it was part of default value, and u didn't assign it to any other key it won't create any key for you.

Comment: @aardvarkk I updated my answer for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

As Md. Farhan Memon already mentioned:

> Basically you are changing the default value and not assigning new key
>   to the hash.

But this is returning what you want:

```
foo = Hash.new({x: 0, y: 0}) # provide a default value
foo[:whatever][:x] += 1
foo['bar'] = foo['bar']
foo #=> {"bar"=>{:x=>1, :y=>0}}
```

First you changed the default value, then assigned to a new key `['bar']` the default value. Works also with `foo['bar'] = foo[:whatever_else]`.

```
foo['bar'] = foo[:whatever_else]
foo['baz'] = foo[:whatever_else]
foo #=> {"bar"=>{:x=>1, :y=>0}, "baz"=>{:x=>1, :y=>0}}
```